# bootstrap layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to give my website a twitter bootstrap layout below. However when I run this code, I don't see any layout in my page while if you look at the example on the link  [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#layouts), it shows the layout on the web page. Any ideas  as to why my layout is does not appear on the webpage?

```
    <html> 
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script></head>
    <div class="container-fluid">
                     <div class="row-fluid" >
                             <div class="span2">

                            </div>
                    <div class="span10">

                     </div>
                     </div>
      </div>

</body> 

</html>
```

Comment: It's not really a programming question but let's say it is for the moment. Please post your whole template!!

Comment: You did have added the CSS of bootstrap?

Comment: a) you're missing the <body> tag, b) how do you expect this to look like? You'll be getting a white page, because there is no content. If you want to look at how your containers work out, give them some background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any content inside - the link you mentioned just shows the example 
which has a style that shows that rectangle: `<div class="mini-layout-body"></div>`

You can see what I mean by this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YYRfq/)

Comment: in that example, you clearly see the layout, how can I make that exact layout visible in my webpage? For instance, can I give a border to the layout to make it visible?

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle if you want to see it exactly like they have it: http://jsfiddle.net/YYRfq/6/

Comment: If you inspect the page elements you can see the css they used.